# transitions when loading a fragment to an activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-transitions

I know there are ways of transitioning from activity to activity and fragment to fragment, but I'm wondering if you can use transitions (i.e. shared elements) when loading a fragment into an activity?

Comment: I think it would be a transition from activity to activity.

Comment: @Ibrahim I know how to do that, I'm wondering how to use a transition when loading a fragment into an activity.

Comment: I'm not transitioning between Fragments. I have an activity with it's own layout, and I want to transition from that layout to a fragment.

Comment: So as i said, it would be a transition from activity to activity because there is no transition between fragment and activity, it's not similar views.

Comment: No, it wouldn't be a transition from activity to activity. What do you mean activity and fragment don't have similar views?

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared element transition by getting the TransitionName pass it  to the fragment (constructor or another way) and set it to new element.

Exemple with ImageView:

```
MyFragment frag = new MyFragment();

String transitionName =  ViewCompat.getTransitionName(sharedImageView);

getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .addSharedElement(sharedImageView, transitionName)
        .replace(R.id.content, frag)
        .commit();
```

In your fragment set the TransitionName to the ImageView.

```
imageView.setTransitionName(transitionName);
```

Here your have a nice article about it:
[Shared Element Transitions](http://mikescamell.com/shared-element-transitions-part-4-recyclerview/)

Comment: The article you posted only goes from activity to activity and fragment to fragment.

Comment: I am assuming you will transition from one fragment to another  inside of an activity. Because fragments live inside activities. Explain a bit better your use case.